# Failed to get data fields inserted into database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have the **[just forms](http://lazy-coding.com/j-forms-full/)** script that generates data fields from form and insert them to the database.

However, when I try to send the data I got message that the data sent, but I actually don't see it in the database.

I have a table inside my database called `cantaki` and it contains these columns:

```
contact_email  
contact_filename  
contact_id  
contact_name  
message  
mysql_table  
subject  
token
```

I try to change the `contact_email` to `email` and so with the others but the data won't insert.

Here is the `actions.php` file:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

    if (!$_POST) exit;

    require dirname(__FILE__)."/validation.php";
    require dirname(__FILE__)."/csrf.php";

/************************************************/
/* Your data */
/************************************************/
    /* Your email goes here */
    $your_email = "mymail@gmail.com";

    /* Your name or your company name goes here */
    $your_name = "david";

    /* Message subject */
    $your_subject = "New message";

    /* Define your data to access MySQL database */
    define("CON_USER", "myDBuser");                 // your username
    define("CON_SERVER", "localhost");                  // your host
    define("CON_PASSWORD", "Mypass");               // your password
    define("CON_DATABASE", "myDB");             // your database

    /* Your database table goes here */
    $mysql_table = "cantaki";

/************************************************/
/* Settings */
/************************************************/
    /* Select validation for fields */
    /* If you want to validate field - true, if you don't - false */
    $validate_name      = true;
    $validate_email     = true;


    /* Select the action */
    /* If you want to do the action - true, if you don't - false */
    $send_letter            = true;
    $upload_file            = true;
    $duplicate_to_database  = true;

/************************************************/
/* Variables */
/************************************************/
    /* Error variables */
    $error_text     = array();
    $error_message  = '';

    /* Last row ID */
    /* In case, if data will not be duplicated to a database */
    $row_id = "No data in a database";

    /* File name */
    /* In case, if a file will not be uploaded to a server */
    $file_name = "No file for upload";

    /* Allowed file types */
    $valid_types = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "application/msword",
                            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");

    /* POST data */
    $name    = (isset($_POST["name"]))          ? strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]))          : false;
    $email   = (isset($_POST["email"]))         ? strip_tags(trim($_POST["email"]))         : false;
    $token   = (isset($_POST["token_contact"])) ? strip_tags(trim($_POST["token_contact"])) : false;

    $name    = htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $email   = htmlspecialchars($email, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $token   = htmlspecialchars($token, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

    $name    = substr($name, 0, 50);
    $email   = substr($email, 0, 40);

/************************************************/
/* CSRF protection */
/************************************************/
    $new_token = new CSRF('contact');
    if (!$new_token->check_token($token)) {
        echo '<div class="error-message unit"><i class="fa fa-close"></i>Incorrect token. Please reload this webpage</div>';
        exit;
    }

/************************************************/
/* Validation */
/************************************************/
    /* Name */
    if ($validate_name){
        $result = validateName($name, 1);
        if ($result !== "valid") {
            $error_text[] = $result;
        }
    }

    /* Email */
    if ($validate_email){
        $result = validateEmail($email);
        if ($result !== "valid") {
            $error_text[] = $result;
        }
    }


    /* If validation error occurs */
    if ($error_text) {
        foreach ($error_text as $val) {
            $error_message .= '<li>' . $val . '</li>';
        }
        echo '<div class="error-message unit"><i class="fa fa-close"></i>Oops! The following errors occurred:<ul>' . $error_message . '</ul></div>';
        exit;
    }

/************************************************/
/* Upload file to the server */
/************************************************/
    /* Upload file */
    if ($upload_file) {
        $file_name = uploadFile();
    }

/************************************************/
/* Duplicate info to a database */
/************************************************/
    if ($duplicate_to_database) {

        /* Select type of connection to a database */
        /* If you want to use connection - true, if you don't - false */
        /* For proper work you have to select only one type of connection */

        /* Mysqli connection to DB */
        $mysqli_connect = true;
        if ($mysqli_connect) {
            require dirname(__FILE__)."/mysql.php";
            $row_id = queryMysqli($mysql_table, $name, $email);
        }
        /* PDO connection to DB */
        $pdo_connect = false;
        if ($pdo_connect) {
            require dirname(__FILE__)."/pdo.php";
            $row_id = queryPdo($mysql_table, $name, $email);
        }
    }

/************************************************/
/* Sending email */
/************************************************/
    if ($send_letter) {

        /* Send email using sendmail function */
        /* If you want to use sendmail - true, if you don't - false */
        /* If you will use sendmail function - do not forget to set '$smtp' variable to 'false' */
        $sendmail = true;
        if ($sendmail) {
            require dirname(__FILE__)."/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
            require dirname(__FILE__)."/message.php";
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->isSendmail();
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->From = $email;
            $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
            $mail->FromName = "J-forms";
            $mail->Encoding = "base64";
            $mail->ContentType = "text/html";
            $mail->addAddress($your_email, $your_name);
            $mail->Subject = $your_subject;
            $mail->Body = $letter;
            $mail->AltBody = "Use an HTML compatible email client";
        }

        /* Send email using smtp function */
        /* If you want to use smtp - true, if you don't - false */
        /* If you will use smtp function - do not forget to set '$sendmail' variable to 'false' */
        $smtp = false;
        if ($smtp) {
            require dirname(__FILE__)."/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
            require dirname(__FILE__)."/message.php";
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = "smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com";        // Specify main and backup server
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                     // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = "your-username";                          // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = "your-password";                          // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                                  // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
            $mail->Port = 465;                                          // SMTP Port number e.g. smtp.gmail.com uses port 465
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->From = $email;
            $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
            $mail->FromName = "J-forms";
            $mail->Encoding = "base64";
            $mail->Timeout = 200;
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
            $mail->ContentType = "text/html";
            $mail->addAddress($your_email, $your_name);
            $mail->Subject = $your_subject;
            $mail->Body = $letter;
            $mail->AltBody = "Use an HTML compatible email client";
        }

        /* Multiple email recepients */
        /* If you want to add multiple email recepients - true, if you don't - false */
        /* Enter email and name of the recipients */
        $recipients = false;
        if ($recipients) {
            $recipients = array("email@domain.com" => "name of recipient",
                                "email@domain.com" => "name of recipient",
                                "email@domain.com" => "name of recipient"
                                );
            foreach ($recipients as $email => $name) {
                $mail->AddBCC($email, $name);
            }
        }

        /* if error occurs while email sending */
        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo '<div class="error-message unit"><i class="fa fa-close"></i>Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '</div>';
            exit;
        }
    }

/************************************************/
/* Success message */
/************************************************/
    echo '<div class="success-message unit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Your message has been sent</div>';
?>
```

Here is the **mysql.php** file:

```
<?php

/* Duplicate information to DB */
function queryMysqli($mysql_table, $contact_name, $contact_email) {

    /* Variables */
    $error_exists = false;
    $error_mysql = "";

    /* Connection to DB */
    /* Constants, that defined in action.php, are used */
    $link = mysqli_connect(CON_SERVER, CON_USER, CON_PASSWORD, CON_DATABASE);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        $error_mysql = ("Error connecting to database (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ") ". mysqli_connect_error());
        return $error_mysql;
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');

    /* Query to DB */
    /* Add data to DB */
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO ".$mysql_table."(`".$mysql_table."_id`,
                                                                    `".$mysql_table."_name`,
                                                                    `".$mysql_table."_email`,

                                                        VALUES (NULL,   '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $name)."',
                                                                        '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email)."')");

    /* Get a last row ID to send in message */
    $row_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);

    /* If error occurs */
    if (!$result){
        $error_exists = true;
        $error_mysql = "Error database query: ".mysqli_error($link);
    }

    /* Return result */
    mysqli_close($link);
    return $error_exists ? $error_mysql : $row_id;
}
?>
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what are the errors/warnings are you getting ??

Comment: i dont. where do i insert the echo check?

Comment: Where did this code come from? It seems broken, fundamentally, on a number of levels. What's going on here is a weak facsimile of what you get, out of the box, with any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/). Tools like 
[Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) and [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) have much cleaner ways of getting this done. This is a lot of code for us to process and identify any things going "wrong".

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: `$contact_name` != `$name` same with email. Error reporting should throw something about that.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Write line ini_set('display_errors',1); after <?php to see errors

Comment: @StackBuck use `error_reporting(-1)` in the very start of this script file, right after opening `<?php` tag

Comment: so what the exact command i need to write? and where?

Comment: error_reporting(-1) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'header' (T_STRING) in /mydir/action.php on line 4